# Jenkins Jacoco Report - unable to exclude packages from the report

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

I am using Jacoco for coverage report generation in Jenkins Pipeline.
Note: This is not a maven based project

**While generating the report I want to exclude some of the packages.**

**For example:** `paclage1` is to be excluded here

---

**Directory Structure:**

```
+ workspace
  + src
     + com
       - package1
       - package2
  + classes
     + com
       - package1
       - package2
  - jacoco.exec
```

---

**For this, I have used the following statement in JenkinsFile:**

```
jacoco execPattern: 'jacoco.exec', classPattern: 'classes/', sourcePattern: 'src/', exclusionPattern: '**/package1/**/*.class'
```

## But in the jacoco report the package and it's classes are not getting excluded

This is impacting the coverage badly.

In the exclusion pattern, I have even tried the following other regex, but still not getting excluded:

```
- exclusionPattern: '**/package1/**/*.class'
- exclusionPattern: '**/package1/**/*'
- exclusionPattern: '**/package1/**.class'
- exclusionPattern: '**/package1/**'
- exclusionPattern: '**/package1/*.class'
- exclusionPattern: '**/package1/*'

- exclusionPattern: 'com/package1/**/*.class'
- exclusionPattern: 'com/package1/**/*'
- exclusionPattern: 'com/package1/**.class'
- exclusionPattern: 'com/package1/**'
- exclusionPattern: 'com/package1/*.class'
- exclusionPattern: 'com/package1/*'

- exclusionPattern: '**/com/package1/**/*.class'
- exclusionPattern: '**/com/package1/**/*'
- exclusionPattern: '**/com/package1/**.class'
- exclusionPattern: '**/com/package1/**'
- exclusionPattern: '**/com/package1/*.class'
- exclusionPattern: '**/com/package1/*'

- exclusionPattern: '/com/package1/**/*.class'
- exclusionPattern: '/com/package1/**/*'
- exclusionPattern: '/com/package1/**.class'
- exclusionPattern: '/com/package1/**'
- exclusionPattern: '/com/package1/*.class'
- exclusionPattern: '/com/package1/*'


And many such more combinations.
```

I have been even tried **sourceExclusionPattern** with the similar set of combinations. But still unsuccessful.

Note: `package1` is just an example here. In actual case, `package1` is something like `debashish/core/extra`

## Need help in finding what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you try using something like (asterix)com/debashish/core/extra(asterix) where (asterix) is the asterix symbol (I cannot post a comment with the asterix in it)

Comment: @mkane Attempted. Didn't work.